# Can i manually change method icon (lock/unlock) in Swagger UI?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, jwt

I have a app .net core 3.0, JWT for authentication, swagger. I create a default login logout using this [guide](https://mac-blog.org.ua/dotnet-core-swashbuckle-3-bearer-auth/).

[image]
When we use default Authorize button

[image]

swagger automatically change icons(lock when we have Authorize) in methods.

Can i change this icons manually when i use my login/logout button?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. You want the lock icons to disappear if you have set an authorization token?

Comment: no. If i use default swagger Authorize button it will change unlock icon into lock => that mean you have token and can make request. But if i use my signin i make request, take token and save it to local storage but i want to show that we have token as a result i want change unlock icon into lock.

Comment: To authorize programmatically you need to call Swagger UI's `preauthorizeApiKey` method ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50181701/113116)). Not sure how/where you would add it to your Swashbuckle config though.

Comment: its not help, as i understand i should change the some state of swagger ui authorized / unauthorized and meaby than icon will change automatically

Answer (score 1):

Install Package

> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters

and when you document your Swagger in your code add below line

```
  options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter >();
```

Here's a full example from .NET 6

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => {
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "API",
        Version = "v1",
        Description = "API using .NET 6"
    });
    options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
});
```

[Swagger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlxXQ.png)