# ExpressJs + Swagger: set Bearer apiKey programatically for deploy

Tags: node.js, express, openapi, api-key

I am currently trying to deploy a **React** app with an **Express api + MongoDb Community**,

In development, I use **Swagger** to manually set up an ***api key/bearer*** :
====> [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmfDP.png)

How can this be achieved (programmatically or automatically) in production mode?

Comment: How i see is even in production mode you want your API to be tested by some other users, so it would make sense to give them a api key.
you can include an api key in your swagger description, that wont be an security risk, automatically this is not achievable because sagger UI act as web page

Comment: thanks a lot for your very quick answer Jatin, I'm gonna take a look at that : )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I automatically authorize all endpoints with Swagger UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45199989/113116)

Comment: Hi Helen, thank you for this link : )

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this can help someone, as [Jatin suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70805532/expressjs-swagger-set-bearer-apikey-programatically-for-deploy/70929663#comment125173451_70805532), the answer was just to edit the swagger file's `Bearer` field from
`Bearer:[]` to `Bearer: 'someBearer'`.